# "Windows Kits\10\Redist\ucrt\DLLs" doesn't exist

Tags: windows, visual-studio, winapi

I am trying to build a WebRTC library. It has a bunch of build python scripts one of which is trying to access

> C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Redist\ucrt\DLLs\x64

And copy ucrt Dlls into build directory.It fails there because my `Redist` directory doesn't have ucrt folder. I tried to uninstall my Windows SDK 10 and reinstall it.But `Redist` is still empty. Based on [this doc](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/vcblog/2015/03/03/introducing-the-universal-crt/) by Microsoft:

> To obtain the binaries for app-local deployment, install the Windows
>   Software Development Kit (SDK) for Windows 10.  The binaries will be
>   installed to C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Redist\ucrt.

But it simply doesn't happen.I also tried to reinstall all the Windows tools and SDK via my VS2015 (Community) installer.

Did Microsoft deprecate the redistributable part of the installation?
How can I solve this?

I installed Windows SDK 10.0.16299.0 . My system is Windows 10 64bit.

Comment: They exist on my installation of WSDK 10.0.16299.0. Try installing the WSDK on a fresh Windows installation - sounds like something might've got corrupted during the setup process on your computer.

Comment: I can't just format my windows machine for this.Also,as I said,I did it several times: standalone version and via Visual Studio.I even did it after major windows update (creative version) which kinda close to a fresh installation.

Comment: Another data point: They exist in my vs2017 (community) installation too - also windows 10 64 bit.

Comment: That was a mess with other versions of the SDK on my machine. I uninstalled them all, cleaned registry. And also uninstalled the VS  .Then reinstalled the SDK. This time got those DLLs in place.

Comment: @MichaelIV: What did "cleaned registry" entail?

Comment: I cannot tell now exactly the details, as it was in the middle of pretty  sleepless week, but I had to open Win registry window and delete entries of the old  nonexistent win SDKs. I guess I read somewhere about it.

Answer (score 1):

It happened to me. Both the visual studio installer and the standalone install incomplete/corrupt versions of the sdk.

Solution: Install the sdk in a windows VM (you can use the Microsoft provided vm: *https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/tools/vms/*) and install the SDK there, then copy the complete folder (named 10 in my case) to the appropriate route. In Windows 10 would be:  *C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits*

(Commenting 4 year later because I came here looking for the same answer :) )